# Keycode in textfield?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin

I need create a class for money values that extends textfield, when I enter with all values I want to format it for money.
I'm reading the book but don't understand how to get the keycodes when I enter with the values.

any idea or example ?

thanks

Comment: 1. What action should trigger the formatting? 2. Where do you want to place the formatted values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 1) add an `Action Listener` which informs you about a key event. Implement the `Handler Interface`:

```
// Have the unmodified Enter key cause an event
Action action_ok = new ShortcutAction("Default key", ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ENTER, null);

Action[] actions = new Action[] {action_ok};

public Action[] getActions(Object target, Object sender) {
    if (sender == myPanel)
        return actions;

    return null;
}

/**
 * Handle actions received from keyboard. This simply directs
 * the actions to the same listener methods that are called
 * with ButtonClick events.
 */
public void handleAction(Action action, Object sender, Object target) {
    if (action == action_ok) {
        okHandler();
    }
}
```

You can add the action handler to a `Panel` or `Window`

```
// Set this object as the action handler
panel.addActionHandler(this);
```

For all information have a look [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.shortcuts.html) especially under 11.5.2 Field Focus Shortcuts.

2) But I recommend to use a [Converter](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter.html) more information [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.properties.html) under 9.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Key code is generated when a keyboard key is pressed/typed/released. All fall in the category of `KeyEvent` in Java. First bind a key listener to the textfield. In that method you would receive an object of `KeyEvent` which has method called `getKeyCode()` giving the key code of currently typed key. For more help, refer to following links:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: @FernandoPaiva - Could you provide the link for Vaadin7? What I found was a Web UI making website and your question is related to Java desktop..